# How to cancel the current input in ed

Tags: ed

In GNU ed, is there a way to cancel the current input? For example:

```
$ ed myfile.txt
1234
a
Wrong speling.
Bad sentance.
```

At this point, I want to cancel the input. I no longer want to insert the two lines that I have typed. Is it possible? I thought of continuing like this:

```
.
u
```

Is using "undo" the usual method for cancelling an input? Are there other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "cancel" input, as in "starting to append several lines of text but then not actually appending them".

While adding text with e.g. the `a` command, a *single* line of text may be cancelled by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice *before* pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Doing so also terminates the current editing command. You can't cancel the addition of more than the current line in this way. Depending on your system and `ed` variant, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice in insertion mode may or may not give you a new line to type the next command on (does on OpenBSD, does not on Ubuntu Linux).

The above "trick" (undocumented feature) does not work if you use `ed` together with `rlwrap` to get command history and Readline editing capabilities.

You can undo the whole operation once you have finished it, just like how you show.  You end the insertion of text with `.` on a line of its own and then issue the `u` (undo) command. You could also end the text insertion with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on a new line and then use the `u` command.

The `ed` editor has a single level of undoing, which means you may undo the most recent command only.  Undoing twice undoes the undo.  If you apply multiple commands to the text with a single `g`, `v`, `G`, or `V` command, then this counts as one single command that you may undo if you need to do so.